# My clock function is not working in a function in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++14, clock

The clock function is not working i guess its giving 0 all the time not even in float.

```
int sequential_search(int *k, int size){
    float x,y;
    clock_t time_req;
    time_req = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<sizeofarray; i++){
      if(k[i]== 10100 ){
        cout<< "Found in: " <<i;
        break;
      }else if(i== sizeofarray-1 ){
        cout<<"Not found";
      }
    }
    time_req = clock() - time_req;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout << "It took: " << (float)time_req/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
}
```

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKjh4.png)

Comment: You should try printing a before and after of the clock to see if both are 0.  It is also possible that your OS does not allow access to this function.  Not likely, but possible.  Since you are converting to seconds, the answer probably is 0.

Comment: Also, your function doesn't compile; and please post a full working example with a `main()`.

Comment: What are you calling with? If the array is sufficiently small, `0` may actually be the right answer.

Comment: sizeofarray should be size?

Comment: Yeah, I think the time it's taking is less than the granularity of `clock()`. I got your code working, and with an array size of 100,000,000 and the value at 90,320,000 it took 0.172 seconds.

Comment: In addition to the above: please copy-paste text, instead of providing screenshots of it.

Comment: using repl getting this and the size of the array is 10100

Found in: 10099
It took: 7.6e-05 seconds

Comment: What is the value of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` on your system?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably occurring because your function is too fast or your vector is too small to be measured.

Try using `std::chrono::milliseconds` to `std::chrono::nanoseconds` or `std::chrono::microseconds`

Comment: using repl im getting

Found in: 10099
It took: 7.6e-05 seconds